# pop3 issue with trying to dowload attachments -C#

Tags: c#, gmail, pop3, openpop

I have been looking high and low for a while to have an easy to use piece of code to have my C# project download a text file attachment on an email from gmail. I did take a look at openpop.net lib, which is the only library I see that seems promising! Can anyone show me some code that gets the job done? I looked at other peoples examples with openpop, but the api was different in their example, maybe older version? Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you would do this using my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library which is vastly more efficient than OpenPOP.NET:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

using MailKit.Net.Pop3;
using MailKit;
using MimeKit;

namespace TestClient {
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new Pop3Client ()) {
                client.Connect ("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);

                // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
                // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");

                client.Authenticate ("joey@gmail.com", "password");

                int count = client.GetMessageCount ();
                int unknown = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    var message = client.GetMessage (i);

                    foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments.OfType<TextPart> ()) {
                        var fileName = attachment.FileName ?? string.Format ("unknown{0}.txt", ++unknown);

                        // Save the content of the attachment in whatever
                        // charset it is in.
                        using (var stream = File.Create (fileName))
                            attachment.ContentObject.DecodeTo (stream);
                    }
                }

                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a lot of messages in your GMail account and/or you just want to download messages with even more efficiency, GMail supports the PIPELINING extension which MailKit can take advantage of.

Instead of downloading a single message at a time, you can use `GetMessages()` to batch request a range of messages which will take advantage of the PIPELINING extension which vastly reduces latency and thus can greatly reduce download times.